# Committing Domain Data before closing Window

Tags: wpf

My view is hosted in a Window with domain data exposed via the ViewModel; and I am overriding the OnClosing event handler of the Window to determine if the domain data was committed to the repository.  If the domain data is committed, then the Window is closed and no further action is required.  However, if the data is dirty, a MessageBox is displayed prompting the user to Save the changes, Cancel the window close operation, or simply Discard the changes.   How do I call my SaveCommand in the ViewModel to commit the changes if the user chooses to save them?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a viewmodel, then your save command should already be in the viewmodel and you should simply have to invoke it...do you already have a button on your view to save your changes? if its using a relaycommand all you have to do is simply invoke the same commandexecute method you are already using...

Comment: The ViewModel inherits a generic base class and the View, Model, and Repository are passed into the constructor and stored in the base class.  The generic ViewModelBase looks like this…
    public abstract class ViewModelBase<V, M, R> : Notifier, IViewModel<V, M, R>
        where V : Control
        where M : IDomainObject
        where R : IRepository<M>

I need a way to cast the DataContext to a ViewModelBase<V, M, R> in order to access both the View and Repository.